# Assets not showing Rails ENV production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, production-environment

I have just pushed some changes to my deployed app (only some view changes which all worked just fine), ran `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` and all of a sudden my stylesheets and images are not being served?

I have checked the html source which shows that the styelsheets and javascripts are being loaded.

```
<link href="/virtual-piano/assets/application-a98a08ba4b9c8c54d0ac4103a8bf4bdf.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/virtual-piano/assets/application-23f71043aa7578f758b9d6244d5bd9b1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The production.log doesn't mention anything about failing to load assets.

I have cleared the cache on my browsers.

Restarted the apache2 server and touched the restart.txt file.

production.rb

```
# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true
```

Im a bit stumped, if anyone has an idea of whats going on it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is there virtual-piano dir in public dir

Comment: Hi amar, um no its only public....the structure is virtual-piano/app/public/assets. It was working just fine before so thats strange. How would i rectify?

Comment: Is the above your entire product.rb? One option that could cause this is: "config.assets_host = '/virtual-piano'".

Comment: Hi max, no its not, i do have some relative path and domain_configs in there tho. DOMAIN_CONFIG = "http://www.domain.com/" &  config.action_controller.relative_url_root = "/virtual-piano" could these be inhibiting the assets?